# How can specify unsigned number corresponding GPIO pin in linux kernel module?

Tags: gpio, driver

I am beginner of linux driver. I want to write my simple module with led. i found some function like `gpio_request(unsigned gpio, const char *label)`, `gpio_export(unsigned gpio, bool direction_may_change)`,...

But i couldn't specify unsigned gpio corresponding with gpio pin. Can you provide some documemnt about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPIO numbered 0 to 53 correspond to Broadcom GPIO numbered 0 - 53.

See https://pinout.xyz/ for the correspondence between GPIO number and Raspberry Pi extension header pin number.

If you are using the new gpiochip interface (rather than the sysfs interface) this assumes you open gpiochip0.

Comment: Ex. Physical pin 15
BCM pin 22
Wiring Pi pin 3. what is unsigned gpio i must pass to function above?

Comment: it is Physical, BCM or Wiring Pi?

Comment: BCM (Broadcom).